# Where should the cable be run on a front derailleur?

Tags: mountain-bike, shifting, derailleur-front

I'm trying to figure out the cable direction on Altus front derailleur. This is a top swing FD. It is shown as below figure on shimano's dealer manual  but it's not much clear.

[image]

Should the cable be guided through the plastic notches (A) or right next to metal plate (B)?
[image]

Comment: I think there's a groove visible on the left side of the scew, where you marked the 'A' position. My guess would be that's where the cable belongs. Not sure though, hence just a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your front derailleur (*FD-M2000*) is dual pull, the cable could either be attached to it in the down pull or the top pull configuration, as pictured below ([Dealer's Manual - General Operations](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/GN0001/DM-GN0001-26-ENG.pdf) on page 44):

[image]

Looking at your photo, since the cable comes from below the derailleur, you must use the **down pull** configuration.

That being said, it is not clear at first glance if the cable must go through what you marked as *A* or *B*. If we look closely at the picture below though, we can see that the cable for the down pull configuration goes through notches which are similar to the notches on your FD for *A* and that *B* seems to have nothing to do with cable routing.

[image]

The groove under the pinch bolt can also gives a clue on where the cable should be coming from (as mentioned in the comments section by @Burki). If the cable is routed through *A*, the groove should be on the left side of the pinch bolt as we want the cable to be pinched straight with respect to the groove.

Comment: B position? Then why those notches are there? Are they for top swing? Actually I'd seen those figures but can't see clearly where the cable is running there.

Comment: @Ender actually, the figure does not look exactly like your Altus FD. I went to see my own Altus FD and it looks more like the picture I posted. What's your exact model number?

Comment: It's Altus M2000: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/altus-m2000/FD-M2000-TS6.html

Comment: @Ender, the more I look at it, the more I think the notches on the picture I posted where the cable is threaded for the down pull configuration maps with the notches you identified with 'A' on your picture. Also, there is usually a small groove under the pinch bolt for the cable. Can you see if this groove is on the 'A' side or on the 'B' side? The cable must be parallel to this groove so it may indicate where it should come from.

Comment: The groove is in line with the plastic notches. Now I'm convinced where the cable should be run through. Thanks a lot. Shimano should have clearer instruction about this on their manuals.